# How to know Runnable scheduled for repeated execution

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I need to run five thread to fetch data from API repeatedly each 20 second ,so I used ScheduledExecutorService.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(Constant.workerThread[i], 0, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

How can I know (at each time) when the five threads are executed?

Comment: Do you have control over the scheduled tasks? I mean, can you change the source code of those Runnable from Constant.workerThread?

Comment: @OctavianR. yes i can change the source code

Comment: @LppEdd I don't understand you

Answer (score 3):

Edit: it appears people don't really get the idea of code snippet. I'll make it bold so that no-one comes up to me again, **manage the inner `ExecutorService` externally, not inside the `Callable` lambda, taking proper care to orderly shutdown it when needed**.

What you can do is manage a single scheduled task, and inside that one, execute your five workers.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
        () -> {
            final ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            final CompletionService<?> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(e);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                // Constant.workerThread[i] is a Runnable
                cs.submit(Constant.workerThread[i], null);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    // Will block until a Future<?> result is available.
                    // Doesn't matter which one, it will take the first available.
                    cs.take();
                } catch (final InterruptedException ignored) {
                    // Ingore the exception, as we care only
                    // about if all off them finished (abruptly or not)
                }
            }

            // All of them finished!
            e.shutdown();
        }, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

*JavaDoc* for `ExecutorCompletionService`

> A `CompletionService` that uses a supplied `Executor` to execute
>   tasks. This class arranges that submitted tasks are, upon completion,
>   placed on a queue accessible using `take`.

*JavaDoc* for `ExecutorCompletionService#take`

> Retrieves and removes the `Future` representing the next completed
>   task, waiting if none are yet present.

This must be refined, but you should get the idea.

Comment: The idea of ThreadPool is to reuse the threads and not to recreate them all the time. The thread creation is expensive and what you have done breaks all principles about thread pools. It's much much better to create the 6'th thread to monitor the completionQueue than recreating the thread pool all the time.

Answer (score 1):

## We run `Runnable` objects, not threads

Threads are not “executed”.

You should be passing a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) in your call to `ScheduledExecutorService::scheduleAtFixdDelay`. I am concerned by your naming `Constant.workerThread`. You don’t pass threads in, you pass the task to run on some thread. You need not worry about which thread runs what `Runnable` task. You need not concern yourself with threads at all. Handling task to be run on threads is the job of an executor, hence the name.

You seem to be missing the basic concepts of threading and tasks. Not surprising as it a tricky subject when first starting out. I suggest studying the Java Tutorials on threading and executors provided free of cost by Oracle.com. Then do some internet’s searches to learn more. Eventually you should study the excellent book by Brian Goetz et al., *Java Concurrency In Practice*.

## `ScheduledFuture` tracks completion

So you won’t be monitoring the threads. Instead focus on your `Runnable` tasks. To monitor their status, capture the [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) object returns by your call to [`scheduleAtFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). Currently you are ignoring those returned objects.

That scheduled future object offers methods to see if the task is complete or cancelled. You can cancel the task as well.

Comment: Constant.workerThread is array of WorkerThread class which is implements Runnable to give me five threds to run

Comment: @EnaamRiyadh You don’t need to manage threads on your own, that is the job of the executor service.

Comment: I don’t want to manage threads I want only to know when the five threads are executed

Comment: Reread my Answer, and do some studying. Threads are not “executed”. You seem to be conflating runnable tasks with threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the source code of your scheduled tasks, you can implement something like this:

```
public class ScheduleExample {

    private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    static abstract class RunnableWithNotification implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public final void run() {
            beforeRun();
            doRun();
            afterRun();
        }

        public abstract void doRun();

        public abstract void beforeRun();

        public abstract void afterRun();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        long delay = 5;
        List<Runnable> tasks = Arrays.asList(
                newRunnableWithNotification(1),
                newRunnableWithNotification(2),
                newRunnableWithNotification(3),
                newRunnableWithNotification(4),
                newRunnableWithNotification(5));

        tasks.forEach(task -> scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    }

    private static Runnable newRunnableWithNotification(int i) {
        return new RunnableWithNotification() {
            @Override
            public void doRun() {
                System.out.println("Executing task " + i);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeRun() {
                System.out.println("Before executing task " + i);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterRun() {
                System.out.println("After executed task " + i);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189714/discussion-on-answer-by-octavian-r-how-to-know-runnable-scheduled-for-repeated). Please make sure to [edit] the answer and include all relevant information from the discussion, for the benefit of future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a sort of execution map.
Always fresh data about the execution state of each runnable.
This is a general example so you need to adapt it to your needs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Application { 
    // Your mocked runnables
    private static List<Runnable> workerRunnables = new ArrayList<>();
    // This will be the map with always updated values, get the map at[i]
    // will return if workerThread[i is running]
    private static Map<Integer, Boolean> executionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final int threadPoolSize = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadPoolSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            workerRunnables.add(() -> {
                try {
                    // Update the map, the runnable has started
                    executionMap.put(finalI, true);

                    // Simulating your API calls with different types of delay
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    if (finalI == 2) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }

                    // Update the map, the runnable has finished
                    executionMap.put(finalI, false);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

        workerRunnables.forEach(worker -> scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(worker, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        Executors.newCachedThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

            @Override
            public void run() {
                scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
                            System.out.println("Runnable number " + i +" is running: " + executionMap.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        });
    }
}
```